# The meaning of $\hom_{\Bbb{F}G}(V_1,W)\oplus \hom_{\Bbb{F}G}(V_2,W)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum

I am trying to prove that:
$$\hom_{\Bbb{F}G}\left(\bigoplus_iV_i ,\bigoplus_jW_j\right)\cong\bigoplus_i\bigoplus_j \hom_{\Bbb{F}G}(V_i,W_j)$$

But I am confused about the meaning of, even:
$$\hom_{\Bbb{F}G}(V_1,W)\oplus\hom_{\Bbb{F}G}(V_2,W)$$
On what and how do the elements of thus space act (in both the internal and external interpretations of the direct sum)?

Comment: It is common to define a direct sum of module homomorphisms by
$$
(S \oplus T)(v_1,v_2) = (Sv_1,Tv_2)
$$
Where $V_1 \oplus V_2 = \{(v_1,v_2) : v_i \in V_i\}$ (so I guess that's the "external" interpretation?).

Comment: Are the sums finite? Else I'm not sure it is true...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ye, I thought the external interpretation would be something along these lines. I guess you would then have to use an isomorphism relating $(Sv_1,Tv_2)$ to $W$ but this (I think) is trivial.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud The source I am using (https://www.math.utah.edu/~rbutler/Representations/Representations.pdf pg6) doesn't explicitly say. But for the purpose of this question I would say yes - they are finite.